# How to parse a site where the session id changes over time

Tags: python, python-requests

How to parse a site where the session id changes over time?

I have parser script. I to save the session to an instance of the class requests.Session().
At first everything is fine and the site returns me a response - 200. After a while, the site starts returning a code - 404. I have to manually get the request from devtools and convert it into code.
In the get request itself, I, as expected, pass cookies, headers, user-agent.
Please tell me what can solve the problem in my case?
Site - https://ostrovok.ru/

save cookies and headers

```
cookies = {
'is_auth': '0',
'user_language': 'ru',
'sessionid': 'O9FGaE5zJz_VmnwqZrFS2GGdSE8CVqGjb9m-A1q3eeM:1qOZ7o:MJJ7hxOeoFInRfpcKWZ0VQD_nt8',
'uid': 'TfTb5WTAzdBJ0ki3Ihe8Ag==',
'csrftoken': 'urJJq6wG6VxbaCQqU0GKomD9zRVHQKHuUuZH1TeNsaccswc4W94Vx6iB5nIc7cH7',
'messages': '',
'otaSelectedCurrencyCode': 'RUB',
'media_advertiser': 'clicktripz',
'_hcfnl_funnel_uid': 'ZMDN4GTAzeBKV+K1t00tlQ==',
'_hcfnl_incognito': '0',
'_ym_uid': '1690357216341267426',
'_ym_d': '1690357216',
'otaSearchFormRooms': '%5B%7B%22adults%22%3A2%2C%22ages%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%5D',
'riskified_sid': 'e07421bd-3ec2-452f-a995-007f3a8fd225',
'_hcfnl_fpr': '810d56c27a20ac43aecb6dd03126442f',
'adrcid': 'A_f20hqRJLC75vGhIIs3uDg',
'_yoid': 'b3881029-a4ce-47e1-8fec-558f4a62b644',
'_yosid': 'e9eeae11-a362-40d8-8c29-ce66fcf3c01b',
'__exponea_etc__': '9ebbce0b-ea02-4a8a-a597-cdb561d39c55',
'intercom-id-uw75u6kt': '33b589b8-6f39-4737-a7c9-81ed28ae842a',
'intercom-device-id-uw75u6kt': '05d2a634-4164-4d2b-ba14-abed7b64b607',
'otaSearchFormTripType': 'tourism_trip',
'_hcfnl_csync_h': '2010657237',
'_gid': 'GA1.2.2067605444.1691035605',
'intercom-session-uw75u6kt': '',
'otaSearchFormFrom': '20230804',
'otaSearchFormTo': '20230805',
'otaPixelRatio': '2',
'otaSearchFormDestination': '%7B%22country%22%3A%22%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%22%2C%22countryEn%22%3A%22Russia%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22courtyard_by_marriott_moscow_paveletskaya_hotel%22%2C%22multicompleteType%22%3A%22hotel%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20Cosmos%20Paveletskaya%20Hotel%22%2C%22nameEn%22%3A%22Moscow%22%2C%22regionId%22%3A2395%2C%22type%22%3A%22%22%2C%22masterId%22%3A%227765017%22%2C%22slug%22%3A%22russia%2Fmoscow%22%7D',
'g_state': '{"i_p":1691125581804,"i_l":2}',
'_ym_isad': '2',
'userlucky': '39',
'__exponea_time2__': '-0.016701459884643555',
'adrdel': '1',
'_hcfnl_hash': '7fe61fde-2519-4838-87c4-19b0825ffeca',
'_gat': '1',
'ost_page_count': '6',
'_ga': 'GA1.1.784299861.1690357216',
'_ga_D1NGWXS6ER': 'GS1.1.1691131113.6.1.1691134328.0.0.0',
```

}

```
headers = {
'authority': 'ostrovok.ru',
'accept': '*/*',
'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
# 'cookie': 'is_auth=0; user_language=ru; sessionid=O9FGaE5zJz_VmnwqZrFS2GGdSE8CVqGjb9m-A1q3eeM:1qOZ7o:MJJ7hxOeoFInRfpcKWZ0VQD_nt8; uid=TfTb5WTAzdBJ0ki3Ihe8Ag==; csrftoken=urJJq6wG6VxbaCQqU0GKomD9zRVHQKHuUuZH1TeNsaccswc4W94Vx6iB5nIc7cH7; messages=; otaSelectedCurrencyCode=RUB; media_advertiser=clicktripz; _hcfnl_funnel_uid=ZMDN4GTAzeBKV+K1t00tlQ==; _hcfnl_incognito=0; _ym_uid=1690357216341267426; _ym_d=1690357216; otaSearchFormRooms=%5B%7B%22adults%22%3A2%2C%22ages%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%5D; riskified_sid=e07421bd-3ec2-452f-a995-007f3a8fd225; _hcfnl_fpr=810d56c27a20ac43aecb6dd03126442f; adrcid=A_f20hqRJLC75vGhIIs3uDg; _yoid=b3881029-a4ce-47e1-8fec-558f4a62b644; _yosid=e9eeae11-a362-40d8-8c29-ce66fcf3c01b; __exponea_etc__=9ebbce0b-ea02-4a8a-a597-cdb561d39c55; intercom-id-uw75u6kt=33b589b8-6f39-4737-a7c9-81ed28ae842a; intercom-device-id-uw75u6kt=05d2a634-4164-4d2b-ba14-abed7b64b607; otaSearchFormTripType=tourism_trip; _hcfnl_csync_h=2010657237; _gid=GA1.2.2067605444.1691035605; intercom-session-uw75u6kt=; otaSearchFormFrom=20230804; otaSearchFormTo=20230805; otaPixelRatio=2; otaSearchFormDestination=%7B%22country%22%3A%22%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%22%2C%22countryEn%22%3A%22Russia%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22courtyard_by_marriott_moscow_paveletskaya_hotel%22%2C%22multicompleteType%22%3A%22hotel%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20Cosmos%20Paveletskaya%20Hotel%22%2C%22nameEn%22%3A%22Moscow%22%2C%22regionId%22%3A2395%2C%22type%22%3A%22%22%2C%22masterId%22%3A%227765017%22%2C%22slug%22%3A%22russia%2Fmoscow%22%7D; g_state={"i_p":1691125581804,"i_l":2}; _ym_isad=2; userlucky=39; __exponea_time2__=-0.016701459884643555; adrdel=1; _hcfnl_hash=7fe61fde-2519-4838-87c4-19b0825ffeca; _gat=1; ost_page_count=6; _ga=GA1.1.784299861.1690357216; _ga_D1NGWXS6ER=GS1.1.1691131113.6.1.1691134328.0.0.0',
'referer': 'https://ostrovok.ru/hotel/russia/moscow/mid7765017/courtyard_by_marriott_moscow_paveletskaya_hotel/?q=2395&dates=04.08.2023-05.08.2023&guests=2&trip_type=tourism_trip&sid=77cfeabe-414d-4f83-9f3e-749ada855e22',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?1',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Android"',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36',
```

}

```
params = {
'session': 'ee51728d-5908-4040-9798-b527f4236201',
'search_uuid': 'dc350caf-6c2b-474f-acfc-9f6f9f3c3917',
'start_page': '1',
'end_page': '3',
'client_uid': 'E5DBF44DD0CDC064B748D24902BC1722',
```

}

```
s = requests.Session()
response = 
s.get('https://ostrovok.ru/hotel/search/v2/site/hp/pages/', 
params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To handle a scenario where the session `ID` changes over time and the site returns a `404` error after a while, you need to persist the cookies and headers between requests. You can achieve this by using the `requests.Session()` object and ensuring that the session remains active across requests.

Comment: Hey, I added the code to the topic. Could you check if I am storing cookies and headers correctly?

Comment: Yes, you have correctly stored the cookies and headers in your code. The cookies and headers dictionaries contain the necessary data to pass along with your request to maintain the session and user context, as if you were interacting with the website using a regular web browser.

Comment: It is clear, but at the same time, after a certain time (5-7 minutes), the server returns json with an error to me, and the status code changes from 200 to 404

Comment: The issue you're facing might be related to session expiration or changes in the website's security measures. When working with web scraping or parsing tasks, it's common to encounter issues with maintaining sessions, cookies, and headers, especially if the website has mechanisms in place to prevent scraping.